# Intermittent 501 response from InvokeDeviceMethodAsync - Azure IoT

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

`InvokeDeviceMethodAsync` is intermittently (and only recently) returning a status code of 501 within the responses (the response body is null).

I understand this means Not Implemented. However, the method IS implemented - in fact, it's the only method that is. The device is using `Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client` (`1.32.0-preview-001` since we're also previewing the Device Streams feature).

### Setup, device side

This is all called at startup. After this, some invocations succeed, some fail.

```
var deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionDetails.ConnectionString, TransportType.Mqtt);

await deviceClient.SetMethodHandlerAsync("RedactedMethodName", RedactedMethodHandler, myObj, cancel).ConfigureAwait(true);
```

### Call, server side

```
var methodInvocation = new CloudToDeviceMethod("RedactedMethodName")
{
  ResponseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
  ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)
};

var invokeResponse = await _serviceClient.InvokeDeviceMethodAsync(iotHubDeviceId, methodInvocation, CancellationToken.None);
```

### What have I tried?

- Check code, method registration
- Looking for documentation about 501: can't find any
- Looking through the source for the libraries (https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/search?q=501). Just looks like "not implemented", i.e. nothing registered
- Turning on Distributed Tracing from the Azure portal, with sampling rate 100%. Waited a long time, but still says "Device is not synchronised with desired settings"
- Exploring intellisense on the `DeviceClient` object. Not much there!

### What next?

Well, I'd like to diagnose.

- What possible reasons are there for the 501 response?
- Are there and diagnostic tools, e.g. logging, I have access to?

Comment: Bonus: I just tried invoking the method using the Azure portal. The first one failed with 501, the second one (a second later) succeeded with 200

Comment: have a look at my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56631201/what-happens-to-azure-iot-hub-direct-method-invocation-if-there-is-no-handler/56639465 also for your troubleshooting issue to figure out a side of the problem, etc. the *Azure IoT Hub tester* can help you well (included a device streams feature): https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1173356/Azure-IoT-Hub-Tester

Comment: More updates in my GitHub issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/2122

Also: the Log Analytics workspace I set up shows that things work correctly, until we've used a device stream. Then, sometimes, we get a good cycle of new connections and disconnections with ConnectionForcefullyClosedOnNewConnection (400027).

I can verify that we're not running the DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString again, nor SetMethodHandlerAsync again, nor using/creating a different DeviceClient. There is only one instance running.

Comment: Could you verify this issue using the *TransportType.Amqp*?

Comment: Are you shure, that your method handler didn't throw exception included checking the response payload for the json formatted text?

Comment: I've engaged w/MS Support and an MS engineer via GitHub. The AMQP protocol stops everything working altogether, and the handler doesn't throw an exception (that would give a different response)

Answer (score -1):

It looks like, there is no response from the method within the *responseTimeoutInSeconds* value, so for test purpose (and the real response error) try to use a [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-direct-methods) to invoke the device method.

You should received a http status code described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-direct-methods).

Comment: Thank you, but that's not the case. I get the response immediately. Unfortunately the documentation you linked doesn't comment on the 501 response code.

Comment: did you try to invoke the device method using the REST? What is the response http status code in this case? Is the 501?

Comment: One more thing, the method name is a case sensitive. If the name is not matching, immediately sdk response http status code = 501. because the method is not implemented.

Comment: Yes, I did, see my comment. The casing is correct. It happens intermittently, and I'm not changing the casing.

Comment: Interesting, note, that the device streams is subscribed on the topic *$iothub/streams/POST#* and the device method on the *$iothub/methods/POST/#*, so that are two different device handlers. I have implemented the device streams feature using the MQTT direct protocol in my *Azure IoT Hub tester* and for my region Central US is working well without any impact each other, in other words, I couldn't replicate your issue. I do recommend for test purpose use this tester (it doesn't using any azure SDKs) as a simulator your end (device or cloud).

Comment: I have been spending days on this.  With my app, based upon the IOT Hub C# SDK Quickstarts InvokeDeviceMethod sample, some times it works well mostly it falls over after one or two commands. My commands are upcased at all stages so case is not an issue. When I get a   ```Response status: 501, payload: null``` The handler is not called. Th entity making the call gets that response instantly.

Comment: Following on .. I get the same behaviour using the Azure IoT Explorer (Preview), Direct Method and PnP Commands (I have a Schema).  And my response timeout is 30 sec .. which means that the quick rebutal is NOT a timeout issue.

Comment: I got the bash  shell curl script ( as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-direct-methods) to work from the Azure portal  with a command with a parameter. I could keep submitting there  with no problems!  But when I did same from my app and from IoT Explorer it worked a time or 2 then got 501s and then when I went back to the the portal bash shell, that was then giving me 501s! :(

Comment: @DavidJones, for testing purposes, could you register a default method handler such as **SetMethodDefaultHandlerAsync** in the device? In this case, any (not registered method) invoking a direct method will have a handler and the response to the caller, so it should be not generate a response status 501, payload null.

Comment: @RomanKiss Thanks for that. I wondered if such a command existed as it could make my code simpler as the commands are dynamic: At startup the actual device (an Arduino) sends a list of the commands it handles and the virtual device that fronts it to the hub then registers a handler for each command. (Actually the same method) I could then just have one generic registration.

Comment: @RomanKiss I was able to send a command that is in my Schema but not implemented, from IoT Explorer. Whilst the system wasn't in errant mode as above (returning {"status":501,"payload":null} ) the default handler worked OK. But when the rest of things went erant, it did too. That is the response at the Invoking thread (and in IoT Explorer)  is simply {"status":501,"payload":null}

Comment: I have noticed that I don't get any 501s until I start sending Telemetry. Even occurs if I have stopped it. :(

Comment: @DavidJones, It's interesting, So, use for invoking a direct method a natural protocol such as the REST (postman). If there is still this issue, use the mqtt direct protocol on the device side. You can use, for instance, the MQTT Client box, or my Azure IoT Hub Tester from https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1173356/Azure-IoT-Hub-Tester, note, that this tool doesn't using an iot hub sdk. Also you can use a m2mqtt library https://www.nuget.org/packages/M2Mqtt/ for quick prototyping the device side using the direct mqtt protocol.